# CSS transition on :after is not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a custom switch checkbox.

Here it is when its un-selected

[image]

and when it is selected

[image]

Which is okay apart from the CSS transition is not working, and the switch jumps when toggling even though I am using:

```
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear;
```

I have put together a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/awLdbzec/4/

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: Have you forgot to save the fiddle ? It's empty

Comment: Sorry, updated my question

Comment: Works just fine here. Using Chrome 42.0.2311.135 on Windows.

Comment: It toggles but it jumps

Comment: I am on Chrome windows - it toggles left and right, but there is no animation when moving from left to right or right to left. It jumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do transitions from/to properties whose value is `auto`
and in your example you're changing the `left` value from `0` to `auto` and the `right` value from `auto` to `0`

you can try animating instead the `left` property, from `0` to `(100% - 24px)` by using `calc()`

```
.switch input:checked + span:after {
    background-color: #fff;
    left: -webkit-calc(100% - 24px);       
    left: calc(100% - 24px);
}

/* for the hover effect */   
.switch input:checked + span:hover:after {
    width: 30px;
    left: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
    left: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/awLdbzec/5/

Comment: `calc` hasn't needed the prefixed versions for a very long time. http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: yes but I would keep them anyway  for older browser and older mobile device, they don't really hurt

Comment: The only problem with that is, the :hover effect when the swtich is toggled to the right - do you see how it overflows to the right? if you compare it to my example, it expand its width to the left when it is on the right

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan the only mobile device that's ever used a prefixed version was iOS Safari 6/6.1 (`-webkit-`).

Comment: Also Safari 6 and Chrome < 26 need the prefix. Keep them or remove them as you prefer. The choice is up to you

Comment: I have fixed the padding issue and updated my jsfiddle, please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/awLdbzec/4/

Comment: If the switch is a fixed pixel width, then you [might as well also ditch the calc and just use px values for left](http://jsfiddle.net/japsufyo/).

Comment: Thank you @FabrizioCalderan! It worked, can I then rely on the calc?